# SP_Send_Dbmail containing comma

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I'm trying to send out csv files through sp_send_dbmail and one of the fields (outcome) has commas in it. When running the code below, it will automatically separate some of the outcomes as two columns.

I've tried changing @query_result_separator, but then it wouldn't separate anything at all, except for the outcome field, which eventually gives me two columns.

```
declare @filename NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @prefix varchar(50)
DECLARE @q varchar(max)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @body = 'abc'

SET @filename = concat('abc_',replace(cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar),'-','_'),'.csv')  

SET @prefix = '[sep=,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ID]'

SET @q ='set nocount on; select right(''"=""'' + cast(ID as nvarchar) + ''"""'', 24)' + @prefix + ',Outcome, isnull(cast(Outcomedate as varchar),'''') as OutcomeDate,isnull(cast(Alerts as varchar),'''') as Alerts
from database.abc.defg'


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@body = @body,  
@body_format ='HTML',    
@recipients = 'abc@defg.com',
@subject = 'abc',  
@query = @q ,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,  
@query_attachment_filename = @filename,  
@query_result_separator = ',',  
@query_result_no_padding = 1,  
@query_result_width = 500;
```